# How to calculate routes for temporarily closed roads due to snow or other temporary incidents

Tags: tomtom

I'm attempting to calculate a route for a temporarily closed road due to snow. I understand that the road will reopen in the summer, but I want to pre-calculate.

I haven't found an option in the documentation except for using the departureTime parameter to obtain the route. Is there a way to do this without specifying the departureTime?